# Vocabulary of line coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems

We can represent a line in 2 and 3 dimensions using 2 and 4 parameters respectively.

For example, in 2 dimensions, we can represent a line using the angle $\theta$ of the normal and orthogonal offset $t$ of the line from the origin. Or, we can use points $x,y$ where $\theta = \text{atan2}(x,y)$ and $t = ||(x,y)||$.

This is in contrast to typical *line coordinates*, which I believe use three parameters.

I am wondering if there is a vocabulary to describe these different representations of **lines**.

Comment: Not sure I follow. A line in 3 dimensions using 4 parameters? A line in 3 dimensions can be represented as $P_0 + t(P_1 - P_0)$, where $P_0,P_1$ are vectors. In fact this representation is valid for $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: I believe you can specify a line in 3 dimensions using $(\theta,\phi,t,\gamma)$ where $(\theta,\phi)$ describe the normal vector to a plane in which the line exists, $t$ describes the orthogonal distance of that plane from the origin, and $\gamma$ describes the angle of the line in that plane.

Comment: Similarly, $(x,y,z)$ to represent normal vector to line that passes through origin, $\gamma$ to represent angle of that line in plane defined by normal vector $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: There are infinite planes which contain a given line. It seems to me that none of your proposed parameters depend upon the line itself but on extrinsic stuff that are not uniquely determined.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your 2 dimensional example. Can you do it for the line $2x+y=3$?

Comment: There are an infinite number of planes through a line in 3 dimensions, but exactly one which has a normal vector through the origin that also intersects the given line. Example "line coordinates for $2x + y = 3$ are $(\frac 6 5,\frac 3 5)$ for the "$(x,y)$" notation and $(\arctan(\frac 1 2), \frac{3}{\sqrt 5})$ in "$(\theta,t)$ notation.

Comment: I like interpreting as lines being more general than points--they contain less information and so you can represent them with fewer coordinates than a point.